# Function that gets a chars array separated by commas

Tags: c, arduino

I have a char array that i get from serial port (Arduino) .
the data is separated by commas so its like this :

```
header:data
```

The chars array that holds this structure is pre defined like this : `char content[50];`

I am trying to write a function , that will get a parameter `content`
and return only the `header` , and then another function to return only the `data`.  I know i have to start with this - but dont really know how to continue:

```
void getHeader( char* localString)
{

  char delimiters[] = ":";
  char *valPosition=NULL;
  char newString=NULL ;

  valPosition = strtok(localString, delimiters); //what is this doing ?
  .... //whats now ?

  //also how do you return the header to the argument
```

I have tried that according to an answer here ,but i get nothing to print:

```
  char delimiters[] = ":";
  char *valPosition=NULL;
  char newString=NULL ;
  char * header = NULL;
  valPosition = strtok(content, delimiters);
   malloc(strlen(valPosition) + 1);
   strcpy(header, valPosition);
       Serial.println(header);
```

Comment: That seems to be only PC-related. The arduino-tag is actually missleading.

Comment: comma? or do you mean colon ? `:`

Comment: the arduino tag is not misleading- this is a code i need for arduino , what is the misleading here? this is my need.

Comment: @Curnelious, it is misleading in the sense that it is irrelevant. You seen to have a generic problem with C code, arduino or not.

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) for `strtok()`. It says

> `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`
>
> The `strtok()` function parses a string into a sequence of tokens..... The `delim` argument specifies a set of bytes that delimit the tokens in the parsed string. ...... Each call to `strtok()` returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token.

That means, when you call

```
 valPosition = strtok(localString, delimiters); /
```

`strtok()` will search `localString` for the delimiter specified in `delimiters`
and if it finds any, it will return the token as a null-terminated string.

**Beware**, `strtok()`

> modify their first argument.

and

> cannot be used on constant strings.

so, the `localString` should be modifiable, i.e., cannot be a string literal.

Next, as per your format, `strtok()` will return the `header`, without the `:`.

so, you need to copy the returned string into another and return that. You can use dynamic memory allocation, as per following algorithm

1. Define a `char * header = NULL;`
2. Check the returned value of `strtok()`, if not NULL, allocate memory to `header`, like `header = malloc(strlen(valPosition) + 1);`
3. copy the data using `strcpy(header, valPosition);`
4. return the `header` from the function.

I hope, you understand that you need to change the function prototype also return a pointer, like

```
char * getHeader( char* localString){....
```

Also, once you're done using the returned value, you need to `free()` it.

Comment: thanks, i dont understand something , what does it means return the token? i just cant seems to understand how this function works . if i have a string called set:abc  , than what valPosition will hold after the strtok()?

Comment: Well as i see strtok is saving internal state. I would like to have a data structure that could be either like header:data or like header:datax:dataz . I was thinkig calling this function few times but since strtok save states i am not sure how should i continue feom here. Can you help me with a specific code lines ? Thanks a lot .

Comment: @Curnelious sorry I was away.

Comment: @Curnelious you are not collecting the returned value of `malloc()`. you need to write `header = malloc(strlen(valPosition) + 1);`, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Curnelious what error? btw, you need stdlib.h and string.h

Answer (score 1):

If `header:data` is the only use case you have you want to look for `strchr()`.

Example:

```
#include <string.h> /* for strchr() and strlen() */
#include <errno.h> /* for EINVAL */

int get_header_and_data(const char * input, char ** pheader, char ** pdata)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == input  
      || NULL == pheader || NULL == *pheader 
      || NULL == pdata || NULL == *pdata 
  )
  {
    /* Trivial case of "no" input and/or missing references to store the result. */
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    char * pcolon = strchr(input, ':');
    if (NULL == pcolon) 
    {
      /* No delimiter found. */
      errno = EINVAL;
      result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Delimiter found. */
      if (pcolon == input) 
      {
        /* No header found. */
        errno = EINVAL;
        result = -1;
      }
      else 
      {
        if (1 == strlen(pcolon)) 
        {
          /* No data found. */
          errno = EINVAL;
          result = -1;
        }
        else
        {
          /* Success. */
          *pcolon = '\0';

          ++pcolon;

          (*data) = pcolon;
          (*pheader) = input;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int get_header_and_data(const char *, char **, char **);

...

char content[50] = "";

 /* Load content here. */

char * header = NULL;
char * data = NULL;
if (-1 == get_header_and_data(content, &header, &data)
{
  perror("get_header_and_data() failed.");
  abort(); /* Or what ever to handle the error. */
}
else
{
  /* Dereference and/or use header and data here .*/
}
```

Please not that on success `header` and `data` (still) refer to the memory of `content`, as well as that on success the latter is modifed.

---

Just for fun, the code above can be shrunk down to:

```
int get_header_and_data(const char * input, char ** pheader, char ** pdata)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == input  
    || NULL == pheader || NULL == *pheader 
    || NULL == pdata || NULL == *pdata 
  )
  {
    /* Trivial case of "no" input and/or missing references to store the result. */
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    char * pcolon = strchr(input, ':');
    if (NULL == pcolon /* No delimiter found. */
      || pcolon == input /* No header found. */
      || 1 == strlen(pcolon) /* No data found. */
    )
    {
      errno = EINVAL;
      result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Success. */
      *pcolon = '\0';
      ++pcolon;

      (*data) = pcolon;
      (*pheader) = input;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```